# Do liquids exist that emit light when vibrational energy is added to the system?

Tags: energy, photochemistry

I am looking for a liquid that illuminates when vibrational energy is added to the system.

It does not have to be strictly chemical, it might as well be something else: maybe a crystal in powder form mixed with some kind of oil, or even algae in a thickish liquid, for example.

Does such a liquid exist?

Comment: If you want a pure liquid to emit light, you'll probably have to vibrate it at very high frequencies with ultrasound, creating [sonoluminescence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonoluminescence), which AFAIK is not entirely understood yet but does not seem to be a chemical phenomenon. Perhaps a more exotic possibility would be a [piezophototronic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezophototronics) solid.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto interesting. At what frequencies are we talking here?

Comment: Well by definition ultrasound means 20 kHz and above. It seems that the exact value used can fluctuate between 20 kHz and 60 kHz (simply because lower frequency ultrasound is easier to produce, I assume), varying with parameters such as the nature of the liquid under sonication and the resonant frequency of the container. I don't really know much about sonoluminescence, but there's a lot you can find on it, if you're curious. The light is incredibly weak and brief, though, so don't expect much.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto would a more viscous fluid give off more light? I'm thinking that the resistance of the molecules would increase the sonoluminescence effect.

Comment: Probably less, actually; the mechanical energy in the system would more quickly be lost in the form of heat while trying to get molecules to scrape past each other.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto yeah that seems more likely. So a less viscous fluid would be better I guess. But as I mentioned in the question, is there any chemical that illuminates when energy is applied? either by pressure or vibration or anything?

Comment: I can't specifically think of one, but I imagine some types of unstable molecules might decompose with the emission of light. Maybe someone knows an example.

Comment: Dioxetanes emit light when energy (heat) is applied.  I also think that @NicolauSakerNeto 's comment is right on target.  Sonication (a way of supplying energy) can cause cavitation (bubble formation and collapse) in many liquids.  Upon bubble collapse, light can be released.

Comment: You could look up triboluminescence, this would fit your description.

Answer (score 4):

Since the process does not have to be strictly chemical and algae is mentioned as a possibility, the answer is yes, a liquid that emits light when shaken does exist and is a well known natural phenomenon - bioluminescent water.

Many ocean [dinoflagellates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinoflagellate) produce light when disturbed, producing spectacular displays in waters worldwide.  The [gif below from Timothy R Fallon via Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Surfing_on_a_bioluminescent_wave_near_San_Diego_2020_%28animated%29_%E2%80%94_upload_by_Mattes_2022.gif) shows surfing on a bioluminescent wave near San Diego.

[image: Surfing on a bioluminescent wave near San Diego]

Many other videos of bioluminescence in agitated ocean water are available, showing the phenomenon in locations as diverse as [the Maldives](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOPliKfxk8Y), [Puerto Rico](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwfG9s1A8pI&t=66s), and [Wales](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWIhn16RsHU).
The dinoflagellates [produce light in response to mechanical stress](https://latzlab.ucsd.edu/bioluminescence/dinoflagellates) as a defense mechanism against predators.

[Liquid-filled orbs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1KEtGpV1BE&t=12s) that glow when shaken or just the [bioluminescent liquid itself](https://pyrofarms.com/products/pyrodinos-with-dinonutrients-300ml) are commercially available.

Comment: Very nice answer after all this time! It's a beautiful phenomenon, both visually and scientifically. Thank you for this contribution.

Answer (score -2):

Find compounds that emit light under photolysis.

As that may involve radical production pathways, one can also try to apply sonolysis to the same compounds as:

H2O (with dissolved O2, N2,..) + Sonolysis -> *H + *OH

[Reference source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3171683/): 'Free radical formation from sonolysis of water in the presence of different gases'), to quote:

"In this case, O2 reacts with •H to form •OH, indicating that the presence of dissolved O2 in water sonolysis gives additional amount of •OH. "

Also:

H2O2 + Sonolysis -> *OH + *OH

Apparently, with applications, [see](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27998731), 'Bactericidal effect of hydroxyl radicals generated by the sonolysis and photolysis of hydrogen peroxide for endodontic applications'.

where it is likely that one may be able to replicate to varying degrees the action of light treatment.

Here is a [source example](https://www.bmglabtech.com/luminescent-abel-antioxidant-test-kit-with-pholasin-for-vitamin-c-type-antioxidants/) citing the action of reactive oxygen species (ROS), which can be created by the UV photolysis of, for example, H2O2 (or sonolysis per reference above):

"In biological systems much attention is focused on the two free radicals, superoxide anion and hydroxyl radical....The generation processes of ROS can be monitored using luminescence. Because of the very weak native luminescence of ROS, both luminol and lucigenin have been used in the past to give measurable signals. However, the luminescence of these two substances is very small compared to that of Pholasin®, which allows precise analysis on very small samples."

So, perhaps try performing a sonolysis of, say, luminol or lucigenin, in H2O2 might be interesting.